Total Probability, Independance
Title: Proving Independence from $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^c|B^c)$
Question:
I am trying to prove that the equation $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^c|B^c)$ implies that $A$ and $B$ are independent.
Definitions:

Conditional probabilities are defined as:
$$
   P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}, \quad P(A^c|B^c) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}.
   $$

Independence between $A$ and $B$ is defined as:
$$
   P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B).
   $$


What I’ve Tried:
Starting with the given equation:
$$
P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^c|B^c),
$$
I substituted the following:
$$
P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^c|B)
$$
Simplifying we get:
$$
P(A^c|B^c) = P(A^c|B)
$$
Question:
How can I simplify this equation to explicitly show that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, thereby proving that $A$ and $B$ are independent? Is there an alternate approach I could take?

Use that $A^c\cap B^c=\Omega\setminus(A\cup B)$.

Continuing $P(A^c|B^c) = P(A^c|B)$ and use equality from comment we have
$$\frac{P(A^c\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}=\frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)} \\
\frac{1-P(A\cup B)}{P(B^c)}=\frac{P( B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Where in right hand denominator we use $A^c\cap B=B\setminus A$ and $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(B\setminus A)$. If in obtained equality we use $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, then simplification will give  $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Thanks was stuck on it for a while.

Write any questions if/when you have any.
